# Как переопределить get_price_html() для вариативных товаров?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть магазин на wordpress+woocommerce. У меня такой вопрос: для вывода цены в секции товара используется функция вывода [get_price_html()](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_product_variableget_price_html/). Как ее переопределить для вариативных товаров таким образом, чтобы ценник выводился не в виде Диапазон: старая цена - старая цена Диапазон: новая цена - новая цена (т.е. 120.000 руб. - 180.000 руб. 90.000 руб.-150.000 руб.) ?

```
<div class="price"><del><span class="amount">120.000&nbsp;руб.</span>
–<span class="amount">180.000&nbsp;руб.</span></del> 
<ins><span class="amount">90.000&nbsp;руб.</span>–
<span class="amount">150.000&nbsp;руб.</span></ins></div>
```

а в зависимости от переключателя-вариатора подстраивался под единственное искомое значение цены (1 позиция 90.000 руб., 2 позиция - 120.000 руб., 3 позиция - 150.000 руб.)
Стандартный код переключателя:

```php
<?php global $product, $post; if($product->product_type == 'variable') { $variable_products = array( 'available_variations' => $product->get_available_variations(), 'attributes' => $product->get_variation_attributes(), 'selected_attributes' => $product->get_variation_default_attributes() ); if
( ! empty( $variable_products['available_variations'] ) ) : ?>
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <?php $loop=0 ; foreach ( $variable_products[ 'attributes'] as $name=>$options ) : $loop++; ?>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">
        <label for="<?php echo sanitize_title($name); ?>">
          <?php echo wc_attribute_label( $name ); ?>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td class="value">
        <select id="<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $name ) ); ?>" name="attribute_<?php echo sanitize_title( $name ); ?>">
          <?php if ( is_array( $options ) ) { if ( isset( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $name ) ] ) ) { $selected_value=$ _REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $name ) ]; } elseif ( isset( $variable_products[ 'selected_attributes'][ sanitize_title(
          $name ) ] ) ) { $selected_value=$ variable_products[ 'selected_attributes'][ sanitize_title( $name ) ]; } else { $selected_value='' ; } // Get terms if this is a taxonomy - ordered if ( taxonomy_exists( sanitize_title( $name ) ) ) { $orderby=w
          c_attribute_orderby( sanitize_title( $name ) ); switch ( $orderby ) { case 'name' : $args=a rray( 'orderby'=>'name', 'hide_empty' => false, 'menu_order' => false ); break; case 'id' : $args = array( 'orderby' => 'id', 'order' => 'ASC', 'menu_order' => false, 'hide_empty' => false ); break; case 'menu_order' : $args = array( 'menu_order' => 'ASC', 'hide_empty'
          => false ); break; } $terms = get_terms( sanitize_title( $name ), $args ); foreach ( $terms as $term ) { if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, $options ) ) continue; echo '
          <option value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '"
          ' . selected( sanitize_title( $selected_value ), sanitize_title( $term->slug ), false ) . '>' . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) . '</option>'; } } else { foreach ( $options as $option ) { echo '
          <option value="' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $option ) ) . '"
          ' . selected( sanitize_title( $selected_value ), sanitize_title( $option ), false ) . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option ) ) . '</option>'; } } } ?>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно воспользоваться фильтрами, изменяющими вывод цен для вариативных товаров, например:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'variation_price_format', 10, 2 );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'variation_price_format', 10, 2 );
```

[Источник](https://businessbloomer.com/disable-variable-product-price-range-woocommerce/)